# EF Code First created two properties for one field

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

In database, I have two tables - Show and Language. Table Show besides other things has Foreign Key to Language. Its one-to-many relationship (Show has one language).

When I run Code First from ADO.NET Entity Data Model creates two properties for language field:

```
public class ShowModel
{
    ...
    public LanguageModel Language1 {get; set;}
    public string Language {get; set;}
    ...
}

public class LanguageModel
{
    ...
    public string Language {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

When I debug on sample data, value of Language field from DB is inserted into string property.

Question is - Why it generates those properties? Is it because I can add Language object into the LanguageModel one, but from DB, it always write to string one?

**EDIT**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<LanguageModel>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Shows)
            .WithOptional(e => e.Language1)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.Language);

modelBuilder.Entity<ShowModel>()
            .Property(e => e.Language)
            .IsUnicode(false);
```

Comment: It's not supposed to be there, language can have only it's id and the string

Comment: This is not part of the language model, its part of ShowModel. Language was generated correctly I'll edit a little bit more main question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are hinting at the fact that the field 'Language' is the foreign key to the Language table for the 'Laguage1' navigation property, then I can give you a couple of pointers:

1. The key in the Language table is your Language property, but might not be marked as the key. EF doesn't figure this out by itself unless you name the field Id or something, or mark it with a [Key] attribute.
2. EF doesn't see the 'Language' field as the Foreign key, but as another scalar property, this will result in having 2 Language fields on the Show property. This can be solved by telling the ModelBuilder to use the proper navigation property.

The syntax to solve no. 2 is similar to this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ShowModel>()
  .HasRequired(t => t.Language1) 
  .WithMany(t => t.Shows)
  .HasForeignKey(d => d.Language);
```

Comment: Yep, thats pretty much the "problem". I'm not exactly sure if it is really problem, but more or else I'm trying to understand why its there.
No.1: So in DB I have Language marked is PK, but this is problem with generating or something else?
No.2: Model builder marked in entity ShowModel Language only as property, but in LanguageModel entity, it created similar code for ForeignKey connected with Show (I'll add code to main post). If I understand it well, if I add this code, I can remove the from ShowModel Language property and keep one from Language mode?

Comment: Maybe I understand the problem. String property Language is value of the field from database and is connected with Language property from LanguageModel? And LanguageModel Language1 is pointer to LanguageModel object?

Comment: If you don't do anything, EF will see the Language property as a scalar property (and save it as a string in the DB). It will see Language1 as a navigation property, and create a Foreign Key for it in the DB (this property will not be visible in your model). If you want Language to be the FK property for the navigation property Laguage1, you have to tell EF that this is the case.

In some cases, EF will detect this from the property types and naming (e.g. Language and LanguageId). But if it is not sure, it will see them as unrelated properties and make a 'behind the scenes' FK.

Comment: If this helped you solve your problem, please mark this as your answer.

Comment: Ok. This scenario, or what are you "solving" count, that I created classes and it generates DB from classes (and model builder)? Because I need to create modelbuilder and classes from DB (Language field in DB is already marked as FK by me). If this solve second scenario (my case), I'll try to reread and hopefully get the idea.

Comment: It doesn't matter how you generate your DB, by hand or from migrations. I just assumed you were doing migrations.

The ModelBuilder makes assumptions about your DB based on your entities. So even if you are doing the DB by hand, you need to tell the ModelBuilder what to expect on the DB side.

Comment: Ok, there might be some missunderstanding caused by me, not knowing right terminology and learning those things. What I currently did was database and just did steps from this [site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/data/jj200620). If still your advices apply to this, I'll try to understand and how to use it exactly.

Comment: OK, now I get what you mean. Language is the value of the Foreign Key property in your DB (a string in your case). Language1 is the Navigation property to the entity LanguageModel. You can use either to update the link between the entities. EntityFramework exposes both by default, so you can opt to use the FK property instead of making an entire Language object when you want to update a Show, and you know the FK.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Sorry for previous missunderstanding and thanks for you your help and patience.